# Return empty cell if one cell in range is blank

Tags: arrays, excel, is-empty

I want to return an empty cell from an Excel formula calculating the return for a range of portfolios for respectively 1, 3 and 5 years, conditional on the life of the portfolio (some portfolios have not existed for more than a few months).

I am using the following formula:

`{=IF($L34<>0;(PRODUCT(1+OFFSET($L34;0;0;1;60)/100))^(1/3)*100-100;"-")}`

If the width (e.g. 60 as in 5 years) is in the horizontal range (e.g. last cell is not empty) then the formula returns the return of the portfolio for the last 5 years. 
The problem is if the width isn't in the range (e.g. last cell in width is empty because the total portfolio lifetime is less than 5 years), then I want the formula to return "-" and not the return since inception. Is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Test to see if that cell is empty/blank and put blank...

```
=if(cell_x="","",your expression)
```

should work... or you may consider replacing cell_x="" with cell_x<5 fir example.